# Laravel - Javascript - save all quantities and id's in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I have the problem to save all product_id's with the related quantitie in a multidimensional array.

I have a laravel foreach loop that gives me every product from a bigger products array.

Every single product has a `data-id` attribute and an `<input type="number">` element to select the quantitie.

Thats how I get all the data-id's and the quantities :

```
$('.update').on('click', function() {
    var ids = $('.list').map(function () {
        return $(this).data("id");
    }).get();

    var quantities = $('input[type=number]').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
});
```

Output of the ids variable: 55,65 
Output of the quantities variable: 1,2

My problem is that I need a multidimensinal array that gives me the right product with the related quantitie.

Something like:

```
var product_data = [
    [0] = "id":55,
          "quantitie":1,
    [1] = "id":65,
          "quantitie":2
];
```

I wasn't able to get it like I need it. I'm still very new to javascript.

Thanks for any help and sorry for my bad english!

---

what I tried:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var product_data = [
            id = ids[i],
            quantitie = quantities[i]
        ];
        alert(product_data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try combining those two arrays together. There are just two assumptions in that

1. Both arrays are the same length
2. Both arrays are correctly sorted

```js
var ids = ["1", "2"];
var quantities = [ "30", "40" ];

var res = [];
ids.forEach(function(id, i) { 
  res.push({ id: id, quantitie: quantities[i] });
});
console.log(res);
```